# Placeholder substitution in a Maven APT page

Tags: maven, apt, doxia

I am working on Maven site documentation for some related projects, and I want to create a hyperlink from one site's documentation to another sites documentation.  The wrinkle is that the URL for the link target depends on a Maven property.

I tried this:

```
{{{http://example.com/site/project-${some-prop}/some.html}the documentation}}
```

but the ${some-prop} placeholder doesn't get replaced, and the APT processor then gets
confused by the first '}'.  Escaping the { and } characters (e.g. `$\{some-prop\}` ) doesn't help, and the following doesn't work either:

```
{{http://example.com/site/project-${some-prop}/some.html}}
```

Is there some other way that I can accomplish this task?  For example, is there a way to define a Doxia macro that could be used to substitute a URL that had the placeholder expanded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using version 2.0-beta-6 or later of the site plugin? Also, does your apt filename ends with a .vm extension (as described in the filtering section of [Creating Content](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/examples/creating-content.html)?

Comment: Thanks.  I missed that section.  (I was searching on 'placeholder' which is the Spring term associated with this kind of thing.)